# Automated chart generation VBA

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, charts

I would like to automate generation new series in a chart that I have created.

I have a vector `P(m)` that goes from `1` to `n_r`. this vector is updated in "time steps" in a for loop that goes from `1` to `Ntime` (`j` counter variable as shown in the code below) I would like to create new series in the same chart for every time my `j` increases, preferably a "scatter with straight lines" chart.

```
for j = 1 to Ntime    
    for m = 1 to n_r
        'calculating the vector P(m)    
    next m

    'code below writes vector P(m) to new columns for every new time step
    'stating in column D    
    For m = 1 To n_r
        Cells(2 + m, 3 + j) = P(m)
    Next m
Next j
```

my P(m) vector writes to the cells shown in the figure below, writes one column to the right for every new j
[image]

the chart where I want to add more series is shown below:
[image]
Any help in the matter is greatly appreciated

Comment: where is your relevant code that creats the `Chart`, and the `SeriesCollection` ?

Comment: The chart has been created not using macros. I am pretty new to VBA programming, so not sure what SeriesCollection is. Sorry.

The chart I want to add the new series to is in a separate sheet called Prt

Comment: Maybe add a screen-shot of your existing chart, and where you want to take the data from to add more `Series` (not sur exactly where is yout `P(m)` vector ?

Comment: Screenshots have been added. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago I had the same problem. I used the code below.

This is not a direct answer to your question but you can use it as a starting point.

My code creates four scatter charts (InsertOptionChart is called four times), and for each scatter chart, it adds dataseries one-by one and sets their formatting (marker, line, etc.)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub InsertOptionChartWrapper()
    Dim ewsOption As Worksheet: Set ewsOption = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Option")
    Dim r As Long: For r = 0 To 3
        InsertOptionChart _
            ewsOption.Range("B30:S65").Offset(37 * r, 0), _
            ewsOption.Range("BD179:CC179").Offset(25 * r, 0), _
            ewsOption.Range("BD180:CC180").Offset(25 * r, 0), _
            ewsOption.Range("B182:B202").Offset(25 * r, 0), _
            ewsOption.Range("BD182:CC202").Offset(25 * r, 0)
    Next r
End Sub

Public Sub InsertOptionChart(rngPlace As Range, rngParty As Range, rngOptionName As Range, rngRisk As Range, rngEv As Range)
    Dim chtTarget As Chart: Set chtTarget = rngParty.Worksheet.ChartObjects.Add(rngPlace.Left, rngPlace.Top, rngPlace.Width, rngPlace.Height).Chart
    chtTarget.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmooth

    Dim c As Long: For c = 1 To rngParty.Columns.Count
        Dim serActual As Series: Set serActual = chtTarget.SeriesCollection.NewSeries()
        serActual.XValues = rngRisk
        serActual.Values = rngEv.Columns(c)
        serActual.Name = rngParty.Cells(1, c) & " " & rngOptionName.Cells(1, c)

        serActual.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
        serActual.Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
        serActual.Format.Line.Weight = 1

        serActual.MarkerSize = 5
        If rngParty.Cells(1, c).Value = "MT" Then
            serActual.MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle
        Else
            serActual.MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStylePlus
        End If

        Select Case Left(rngOptionName.Cells(1, c).Value, 1)
        Case "S" ' Spot
            serActual.MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        Case "A"
            serActual.MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(237, 169, 90)
        Case "B"
            serActual.MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(159, 76, 151)
        Case "C"
            serActual.MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(100, 185, 228)
        Case "D"
            serActual.MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(64, 143, 154)
        Case "N" ' None
            serActual.MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(226, 0, 116)
        End Select

        Select Case Right(rngOptionName.Cells(1, c).Value, 4)
        Case "2019"
            serActual.Format.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSolid
        Case "2020"
            serActual.Format.Line.DashStyle = msoLineLongDash
        Case "2021"
            serActual.Format.Line.DashStyle = msoLineDash
        Case "2022"
            serActual.Format.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSquareDot
        Case Else
            serActual.Format.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSolid
        End Select

        serActual.MarkerBackgroundColorIndex = 2
        serActual.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = serActual.MarkerForegroundColor
    Next c

    chtTarget.Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Delete
    chtTarget.Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlLow
    chtTarget.Axes(xlCategory).MajorGridlines.Delete
    chtTarget.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabelPosition = xlLow

    chtTarget.Legend.Font.Size = 8
    chtTarget.Legend.Top = 0
    chtTarget.Legend.Height = chtTarget.Parent.Height
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
This helped a lot :)